# Are questions about research, perception, history regarding sustainable living ontopic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I am curious if questions about the topic of *living sustainable* (whatever that may mean) would be ontopic or if the site's focus is more like a How-to and methodological advice approach. I'm thinking of research that is going on regarding sustainable living.

For example, what about questions like:

- What is the general consumer perception about ecolabels? A question asking for results from empirical surveys.
- Which county in the United States was the first one to employ an expansive recycling system? Basically a question about history.
- How can Life Cycle Analysis and Data Envelopment Analysis contribute to reduce the environmental impact of a given product? A question asking for advice on scientific methodologies.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if it is well balanced and maybe/ideally linked to the present then this should be a good idea.

Studying sustainability itself or its history can be a relevant information to act better now and so it could be welcomed if ask properly maybe.

If/when it is only to study it but without bringing anything relevant for nowadays acting, this might be less worthy and slightly "off-topic" maybe. (I mean, I can clearly see why you asked the question. The answer doesn't seem to be an obvious "yes" from my point of view)